# The property or field 'ItemCount' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, client-object-model, event-receivers

I have the following code inside our server-side event receiver, the code should connect to a sharepoint online list and get the total number of items, here is the code:-

```
   try
   {
     currentItem["Status"] = "Pending";
     if (currentItem.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Contains("project"))
        {

           using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://***.sharepoint.com/"))
           {
             string s = "***";
             SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
             foreach (var c in s)
             passWord.AppendChar(c);
             context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@****.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);
             List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project");
             context.ExecuteQuery();
             var countItems = list.ItemCount;
           }

        }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     var errormessage = e.Message;
   }
```

but i am getting this exception:-

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The property or field 'ItemCount' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject.CheckUninitializedProperty(String propName)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List.get_ItemCount()
       at OrderManagement.EventReceiver1.EventReceiver1.ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
  InnerException:
```

So can anyone advice how i can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't load the list yet.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lee"))
            {
                string s = "password";
                SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                foreach (var c in s)
                    passWord.AppendChar(c);
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);
                List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList");
                context.Load(list);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                var countItems = list.ItemCount;
                Console.WriteLine(countItems);
            }
```